# How to destroy session in client-sessions

Tags: node.js, session-cookies

If I am using client-sessions in NodeJS and wish to completely remove a session, how do I go about doing so?  It seems that calling reset() just clears the session contents, effectively issuing a new session and updating the cookie with a new, extended expiry.

In this case, I wish to remove the session cookie altogether under certain circumstances (logout, etc.).  Does anyone have any tips on how to do so?

Answer (score 3):

In a router like so...

```
router.get('/logout', function (req, res, next) {
    var session = require('client-sessions');
    req.session.reset();
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
req.[session].reset()
```

where [session] is the name of your cookie.